# How to edit the options of an existing container?

Tags: docker

I have a container created (`docker create`) from an image which was using `EXPOSE 22` in the `Dockerfile`

I start it via `docker start <container name or ID>` and access it via `ssh`.

I now need to expose one more port, of a service running in this container. I cannot recreate it, it has to have its startup parameters changed in order to expose that extra port. **Is this possible?**

I was hoping that `docker start` would allow for the same parameters as `docker create` or `docker run` but this is not the case.

Note: I know that the philosophy of docker is to [create ephemeral containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/containers-should-be-ephemeral). It is a fact of life that I have to deal with this heavily customized container (as opposed to recreating it)

Comment: No this is not possible with a running container. If you need to frequently do things like this, docker may not be the best option. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897743/exposing-a-port-on-a-live-docker-container/19905563#19905563

Comment: @jscott: and what about stopping the container, which then would be customized, and restarted? I am wondering if the "customization" part is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're implying you didn't use `docker-compose` to start it, but a normal `docker run`. I would look into `docker-compose`, because then you could have stopped it, and started it again with a new config file. This allows for *reproducible creation* of a container. All the examples of just using `docker run` you see everywhere don't help matters.

In your particular case, I think all you have to do add an `iptables` rule. By default, `dockerd` manipulates the `iptables` rules to redirect traffic (it may even be the only thing `EXPOSE` does). If you do `iptables -t nat -L -n` you can probably see how your ports were exposed. You can create a similar rule.

This does mean that when you restart your server, the rule is gone again. You'll have to save your `iptables` state. And this then also touches the inconvenience of `dockerd` manipulating `iptables`. It's hard to manage next to other services touching iptables (like central configuration systems, `fail2ban`, or even a simple auto-save of your rules).

Comment: Thank you, this is excellent information!. I have a comprehensive management of `iptables` on that server and your information saves my day. I did not realize that `EXPOSE` and `-P` were indeed manipulating `iptables` rules. As a test I added another port for `sshd` and was able to access it by working with `iptables`. Thank you again.

Comment: As a side note, in the general context of my question about changing a container configuration - do you know whether this is possible (outside of my specific case of networking)? I am thinking about the information available via `docker inspect <container>`.

Comment: @WoJ glad I could help. And about the second comment: I was actually briefly looking at that, also particularly the output of `inspect` (perhaps that is stored somewhere and can be edited), because it does seem that should be possible. But, I don't really have the time to look further :).

Comment: Sure, thanks for all your help. I was just asking in case you know it off your head (or that this is customary knowledge in the docker world I am just joining). I will look further down that way to future-proof other containers I may inherit.

Answer (score -1):

you can open the port in the create command.
to open port 80 for example one would run.

```
docker create -p 80:80 container/name
```

more info can be found on
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/

Comment: I do not create and start a new container with `docker run`, I start an existing one with `docker start`. The option you mention is not available for the  `docker start` command.

Comment: you can not add new port to running containers. that is not rely the docker way. what you could do is create your own docker file based on the one you are using and then add all the tools you need via this docker file.

Comment: one of the first things i learned when starting with docker is that if you have to ssh in to a container you are doing it wrong. if you have some heavy custom config i would suggest putting it in a volume

Comment: I somehow "inherited" the container as it, so the only thing I can do is to customize it.