# Docker how to explicitly allow any two containers to communicate, disallow by default

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, docker, containers

With the new docker custom networks, if you want to disallow inter container communication by default and explicitly define any pair of containers that can communicate, you would need to create up to 2^N networks (where N = number of containers) and attach exactly two containers to each network. Are there are any drawbacks to doing this?

Furthermore, if I only want to allow outbound connections from `webServerContainer` to `dbContainer`, but not inbound from `dbContainer` to `webServerContainer`, is there a way to do so?

It seems like using `icc=false` and the legacy `--link` feature allowed something like this, but the feature is marked as deprecated.

For example:

- I have 1 database container
- I have N stateless containers that need to read/write to the database
- I would like to allow each of the N stateless containers to talk to the database container, but prevent connections between any pair of the N stateless containers
- If I put all my N+1 containers in the same user defined `database-access` network, any pair of them could talk to each other which is not what I want
- Furthermore, ideally I want my N stateless containers to be allowed to initiate connections to my database container, but I do not want my database container to be able to initiate connections the other way

Does anyone have advice on the best way of achieving this, as of Docker 17.12?

Answer (score 1):

My answer may not be the most dockerish way, but still helpful, I hope.

My preferred way of doing this, is manually. Docker manipulates iptables to achieve the access rules and inter-container communication. I personally don't like this (for several reasons; the state of iptables usually becomes a big mess, especially of other software manipulates iptables too). So, I set `"iptables": false` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` to false:

```
# cat daemon.json 
{
  "iptables": false
}
```

And the just configure the networking like you would when routing traffic between networks.

This also means you need to set up port forwarding (or HTTP proxying, etc) to access the containers from outside the box, and that you have to define you own docker networks (`docker network`).

My answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/818124/31475) may also be of help.